# Load Prefab to variable

Tags: c#, unity

I have my code, for my weapon:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class Arma : MonoBehaviour {

    public static int municao;
    GameObject bullet;
    GUIText texto;
    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () 
    {

        //bullet = GameObject.Find("Bullet");
        municao = 10;
        texto = GameObject.Find ("qtdMunicao").GetComponent<GUIText>() as GUIText;
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {

        texto.text = municao.ToString ();

        if(Input.GetKeyDown("i"))
        {
            if(municao > 0)
            {
                Instantiate(bullet, transform.position, transform.rotation);
                municao--;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

`

How can i load the prefab to my variable to use in my instantiate?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Assign a ScriptableObject to MonoScript through code](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/121950/assign-a-scriptableobject-to-monoscript-through-code)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `Load` method from the [Resources API](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Resources.Load.html):

```
// Instantiates a prefab named "enemy" located in any Resources
// folder in your project's Assets folder.
void Start() 
{
    GameObject instance = Instantiate(Resources.Load("enemy", typeof(GameObject)));
}
```

Comment: So, if i have a prefab in a folder called "Prebas" named Bullet, i can do like this ? bullet = Resources.Load("Bullet", typeof(GameObject)); ??

Comment: Yes, but everything has to be inside a "Resources" folder. So you should have a path "Resources/Prefabs/Bullet.prefab" and then you could call `Resources.Load("Prefabs/Bullet", ...)`. That should do the trick ;)

Comment: So i need to make a folder called Resources ?

Comment: Yep, the "Resources" folder is mandatory. The "Prefabs" folder I used in the comment above is optional.

Comment: ok, i have a folder called Scripts, and another called Prefabs, so i will put both inside this "Resources" folder, and it should work, right ?

Comment: You shouldn't need to move "Scripts" into the "Resources" folder, but since you are moving the prefabs, might be a good idea to keep everything inside "Resources". Anything you load using the `Resources` object must be inside a directory called "Resources". So the "Prefabs" dir definitely will have to go there.

Comment: it worked perfectly, thank you, but now i have another question

Comment: since i have a bullet for my weapon, the right way to shoot this bullet, is instantiating a prefab, and not a game object that is in the game right?, this way i don't need to put the bullet in the game just to use it, right ?

Comment: I think the way you are doing is fine. Make sure you do the `Resources.Load` in the `Start()` method. Save the return value of Load into a class variable. Then, whenever you want to shoot a bullet, just call `Instantiate` using the stored variable.

Comment: yes, i'm doing exactly this

Answer (score 0):

You can drag-and-drop objects from the Project view just as you would in the main scene, linking them to variables in the Inspector.

That is, click-and-drag the prefab asset in the Project view, and then drop it onto the variable in the Inspector.

Comment: in c# script, the variable does not appear, that's why i'm trying this new way, thank you

Comment: If it doesn't appear, then you didn't write the code properly, because I assure you I do that all the time. Looking at the code you posted, the issue is that you need to declare the variables as 'public'. In your other question you claimed to already know about the code I posted, but clearly you do not.