# Assign a ScriptableObject to MonoScript through code

Tags: unity, c#

Sample code:

```
public class Item : MonoBehavior
{
    public ItemObject item; //the scriptable object

    void Start(){ // do stuff}

}
```

Normally I would drag and drop the asset of the `ScriptableObject` in the inspector.

How can I find and assign the asset (from Project View) through the script during runtime and possibly add it to a `List<>` or `Array[]`?

Comment: I don't see how this is a duplicate to one provided. GameObjects and ScriptableObjects are two different beasts.

Comment: @byte56 This question is definitely not a duplicate! The "duplicate" provided has nothing to do with my question. I asked about .Assets from the library and the "answer" was for GameObjects in the scene.

Comment: I dont think its a duplicate too. How do we unduplicate it ?

Comment: @Byte56 Can you revise your judgement of this "_exact_ duplicate"?

Comment: `Resources.Load()` is generally the way you get assets from the Project directory. Note that the object must be somewhere inside a folder called Resources. (`Assets/Resources/[object]` is fine, so is `Assets/Objects/Resources/Scritable/[object]`)

Comment: @Draco18s so as long as there is a folder named resources it will load the asset? When the game is built will it continue to work?

Comment: Yes. The "Resources" folder is sort of a "keyword" that tells the compiler "bundle this stuff, it's used by code." See [the docs](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Resources.Load.html).  Loading things, per my examples, would be `Resources.Load("[object]")` and `Resources.Load("Scritable/[object]")` respectively.

Comment: @Draco18s Ok, subquestion though, with `Resources.Load("")` how could I ganerate a `List<>` or an `Array[]` of all the resources?

Comment: Resources.Load returns an `Object` by default. You just need to cast it, or use `Resources.Load("") as [Whatever]`.  Mind, I don't know what Type "the entire contents" is returned as.  Exercise for the reader.

Comment: I'm left wondering why do you want to attach assets during runtime and not in editor? Sounds a bit counter productive to be honest.

Comment: @volvis It might be. The general idea is to make a system. A general template (`ScriptableObjects`) for all weapons and only one script in the scene that will load any one of the `weapons.asset` to the scene. From all the ideas I've had on how to make such a thing this was my best one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Acually you want to load resource from your project views [there are 2 ways to do this](http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/LoadingResourcesatRuntime.html).*(which I know if somebody know more then surely update this answer)*

1. [Resource.Load](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Resources.Load.html)
2. [Asset Bundles](https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/topics/scripting/assetbundles-and-assetbundle-manager)

**1 . Resource Example**

```
void Start() {
        GameObject go = GameObject.CreatePrimitive(PrimitiveType.Plane);
        Renderer rend = go.GetComponent<Renderer>();
        rend.material.mainTexture = Resources.Load("glass") as Texture;
    }
```

while "glass" is located inside Resource Folder of your project view. You must need to make Resource folder to use this. You can also check [LoadAssetAtPath].
[4](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/AssetDatabase.LoadAssetAtPath.html)

**2. Asset Bundle Loading example(for detail refer to above link).**

Comment: I like `Resource.Load()` better. Now let's say that we have a folder `Assets/Resources/Items`, how can I get the number of assets inside it and then create an `Array[]` that holds the names of the assets without hardcoding it? The purpose is that when a new asset file is created, it will be automatically added to the game through that code.

Comment: man you don't need to count it use List instead of array[]

Comment: Supposedly I use the List. Then what? Do I hardcode every .asset or is there a way to get let's say the whole Resources folder in there?

Comment: public static Object[] LoadAll(string path); this will return u whole array

Comment: `public static Object[] weaponArray = Resources.LoadAll("Assets/Resources/Weapons");` like this?